# ios 6 auto layout constraints error

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios6, autolayout

I am having an error in my iPad project with auto layout constraints. It's happening with a custom UICollectionViewCell I've created in IB, when I rotate the device to landscape. The thing is that none of the constraints are deletable. I'm still learning auto layout, so I'm sure it could just be a matter of adding some restraints and deleting some of the default ones, but I'm stuck. It's definitely happening with my custom cell - when I remove it and use a plain old UICollectionViewCell I get no error.

I searched around and I tried setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints on my custom cell to NO but then I get the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:     'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. UICollectionView's implementation     of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'

Works fine to set it to NO on the subviews of my custom cell, but when I set it on the cell itself it barfs.

Here is the auto layout constraint error I'm getting - it's the usual one:

> Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)
>
> (
>   "NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x76bf950 h=-&- v=-&- CMAGalleryCollectionViewCell:0x7687690.height == UICollectionView:0x9161e00.height - 875",
>
> "NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x76693c0 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x7665470(704)]",
>
> "NSLayoutConstraint:0x7665850 UICollectionView:0x9161e00.bottom == UIView:0x7665470.bottom",
>
> "NSLayoutConstraint:0x7665740 V:|-(0)-[UICollectionView:0x9161e00]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7665470 )"
>   )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
>   NSLayoutConstraint:0x7665850 UICollectionView:0x9161e00.bottom == UIView:0x7665470.bottom

Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the list of constraints from the error log as well

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but where exactly would I find the error log?

Comment: Right underneath the error you quote above. It will be a list of constraints inside angle brackets.

Comment: Oh right. Added to original message. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've hit this a lot. When you rotate the device/application the width/height of the view change to fit the new orientation screen, and that often breaks a "width = 320" type constraint.

I found the exception above to be unreadable until I'd read this:
   http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/formatLanguage.html

... which is similar to the format shown, and then it became quite easy to see what was a problem.

The non-deletable constraints you are seeing can be altered. You can lower the priority from 1000 to something that can be broken or you can replace them with something that works. One (imperfect) approach might be to make a rule >= 320 so things could stretch for landscape, or you could add your own constraints to give (perhaps tying the view to it's superview, and then the width constraint should be deletable.) That said, that is not a good solution.

I'd recommend you typically attempt to remove width and height constraints where at all possible on something (like a large collection view) that should react to the shape/size of the main view 'cos those widths/heights will typically be wrong 50% of the orientations.

That all said, is this saying the cell height is collection height minus 875?

CMAGalleryCollectionViewCell:0x7687690.height == UICollectionView:0x9161e00.height - 875",

Is this cell a sub view of the collection view and not a template for cells? I've had that problem with interface builder and collections also. I had to rebuild the collection view from scratch in IB to not add a bogus child cell.

Comment: Thanks, let me try this and I'll let you know.

Comment: Still don't understand how to see what's going on. I added the errors to my original post. I can tell from "NSLayoutConstraint:0x7665850 UICollectionView:0x9161e00.bottom == UIView:0x7665470.bottom" it's complaining about tying the bottom of a collection view to the parent view. I can't make head or tails of this one "NSLayoutConstraint:0x7665740 V:|-(0)-[UICollectionView:0x9161e00] (Names: '|':UIView:0x7665470 ) and am not sure why there are autoresizing masks or why I'm getting the error I am when I try to set  translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints on my custom cell.

Comment: V = vertical, | = superview, -(0)- = no separation ... so binding the bottom of the collection view to the bottom of the main view. I suspect this competes with height 875 when the view space on the device is not 875 high. That help?

Comment: BTW: It is translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints on the main UIView that is allowing those special constraints (not affected by the setting down your custom cells.) They might seem  old school, but they actually do a good job of sizing the view (to orientation screen dimensions.)

Comment: Interesting...I built the CMAGalleryCollectionViewCell in IB and the view with the collection view in a Storyboard, so I'm not sure exactly where the CMAGalleryCollectionViewCell:0x7687690.height == UICollectionView:0x9161e00.height - 875 constraint is originating from. I'll see if I can find it but maybe it's something that is being defined by the collectionViewLayout of the collection view, specifically the UIEdgeInsets I'm defining for landscape view? Thanks!

Comment: Here are the values for setting the size and edge insets for the cells in each orientation (landscape and portrait)

Comment: float const kCollectionViewEdgeInsetTopPortrait = 32.0f;
float const kCollectionViewEdgeInsetLeftPortrait = 55.0f;
float const kCollectionViewEdgeInsetBottomPortrait = 32.0f;
float const kCollectionViewEdgeInsetRightPortrait = 55.0f;
float const kCollectionViewEdgeInsetTopLandscape = 32.0f;
float const kCollectionViewEdgeInsetLeftLandscape = 32.0f;
float const kCollectionViewEdgeInsetBottomLandscape = 32.0f;
float const kCollectionViewEdgeInsetRightLandscape = 32.0f;
float const kCollectionViewSpacingBetweenRows = 32.0f;
float const kCollectionViewSpacingBetweenItemsSameRow = 16.0f;

Comment: float const kCollectionViewCellWidth = 300.0f;
float const kCollectionViewCellHeight = 85.0f;
float const kCollectionViewCellBorderWidth = 1.0f;

Comment: One thing to note about IB is (IMHO) it is currently in an uncomfortable spot between two paradigms, and trying to deal with both. If you lay something out with IB using constraints then (just to polish the look) you drag/move something a few pixels, all of a sudden your constraints are replaced, strange height/positioning constraints appear, and things are all messed up. Move view X and even view Y can be altered. Not fun. I've learned to do all/everything w/ constraints in IB to reduce this risk. Look below  view for it's h/w constraints.

Comment: in case it wasn't obvious fogwolf, I don't believe your values above are relevant to this particular problem. Perhaps do what I've done too many times and re-build things from scratch (if possible w/ a lot of pain.) I've had to to "clean out"/simplify constraints.

Comment: And the "cell" as a child subview of a collectionview was something I achieved (and struggled with for too long) with IB. It is great that current IB supports cell templates for tables, but be careful your collection cell is such, and not a subview 'cos thar be dragons...

Comment: Thanks Adam. I've decided to let this warning be for the time being. At some point will revisit and try again from scratch, mostly likely, as you suggest.